What data structure should I use for cashing my resoures when loading in parallel?
I'm working in C#. For a project of mine I need to load in some resources, I don't have any experience working with threads so after some googling I built a system that works 90% of the time. Obviously crashing 10% isn't going to cut it, so I'm hoping a Master of Thread Locking can tell me what I'm doing wrong.
I think my main issue is I don't know how to properly organize the data so It's accesable by multiple threads. Any input is appreciated :)
Here's a boiled down version of what I've written. There's a big tree of resources, many dependant on other resources, no loops. I don't know what resources have already been loaded into the cashe from previouse load calls, so I have to check. Problem is a Dictionary doesn't support concurrent operations, even when I lock the id for accessing the resource.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Sourceage.IO.Interface;
using Sourceage.Element;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace NameSpace
{
    public class Progress
    {
        private float _value;
        private BackgroundWorker _worker;
        public Progress(BackgroundWorker worker)
        {
            _worker = worker;
        }
        
        public void Report(float value)
        {
            lock(this)
            {
                _value += value;
                _worker.ReportProgress((int)_value);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class MyClass
    {
        //Id to factory function, accepting an array of dependencies
        private Dictionary<int, func<object[], object>> _idToFactory = new();
        
        //Id to function providing dependency ids
        private Dictionary<int, func<IEnumerable<int>>> _idToDeps = new();
        
        //Id to cashed instance of resource
        private Dictionary<int, object> _cashe = new();

        //Creates a background worker for loading the given resource
        public BackgroundWorker CreateLoadWorker(int id, Action postWork = null)
        {
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                worker.ReportProgress(1);

                var progress = new Progress(worker);

        var idToDep = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<<int>>();
        CollectDeps(id, idToDep);
        LoadResource(id, idToDep, progress, 98f);

                e.Result = _cashe[id];

                worker.ReportProgress(100);
                postWork?.Invoke();
            }

            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;

            return worker;
        }

        //recursivly collects dependencies for the resource
        private void CollectDeps(int id, Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<<int>> idToDep)
        {
            if (!idToDep.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                var deps = _idToDeps[id]();
                idToDep.Add(id, deps);

                foreach (var dep in deps)
                {
                    CollectDeps(dep, idToDep);
                }
            }
        }

        //recursivly loads resource and its dependencies
        private void LoadResource(int id,
                                  Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<<int>> idToDep,
                                  Progress progress,
                                  float progressAlotment)
        {
            var deps = idToDep[id];
            lock (deps)
            {
                
                //this will crash due to concurrent operations not being supported,
                //but the lock above should mean only one thread can be using the 
                //id at a time
                if (_cashe.ContainsKey(id))
                {
                    //already loaded
                    progress.Report(progressAlotment);
                    return;
                }

                //dependencies
                var depProgressAlotment = progressAlotment / (deps.Count() + 1);

                Parallel.ForEach(deps, (dep) =>
                {
                    LoadResource(dep, idToDep, progress, depProgressAlotment);
                });
        
                //this will sometimes crash due to id 'x' not being present in the cashe
                //but I don't think I should be able to get here without each dep id 
                //already being assigned by the Parallel above
                _cashe[id] = _idToFactory[id](deps.Select(x => _cashe[x]));

                progress.Report(depProgressAlotment);
            }
        }

        public object GetResource(int id)
        {
            var doneEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            var worker = CreateLoadWorker(assignedIds, () => doneEvent.Set());
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            doneEvent.WaitOne();

            return _cashe[id];
        }
    }
}


You could try the  ConcurrentDictionary - ”Represents a thread-safe collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.”

Are you solving a problem that actually exists? Does a TAP version of your code really fail to the extent that MT is mandatory?

Since you don't have any experience working with threads, you are going to struggle. Multithreading is not trivial, and common wisdom does not apply. To write a correct multithreaded program you have to know what you are doing, and also be diskiplined. The compiler can't help you detect the bugs, you have to be aware of them yourself. The error messages won't help you either, because they just indicate that the state of your program became corrupted, and the actual bug will be unrelated with the line of code that throws the error.
The basic rule in multithreading is that when dealing with non-thread-safe components like the Dictionary<K,V>, every access to the component must be synchronized. This means that only one thread at a time should be allowed to interact with the component. You can't be choosy, every single operation must be synchronized with the lock statement, using always the same locker object. Even reading the Count of the dictionary must be synchronized. Even using auxiliary facades of the dictionary, like Keys, Values or an enumerator must be synchronized. A single unprotected access to the dictionary renders your program incorrect, and its behavior undefined.
My advice would be to spend some time, maybe a week, and study multithreading systematically. A good online resource is Threading in C# by Joseph Albahari. This will help you write correct programs with predictable behavior that you'll be able to maintain in the long run. Without knowing what you are doing, you are just going to create a mess.
